# What java api can we use to connect to jUDDI V3 in an upgrade from V2?

Tags: upgrade, uddi

We are upgrading some of our systems including a move up to jUDDI V3 from V2. In the past we used uddi4j in our java code to access the UDDI server, but uddi4j doesn't seem to have continued to V3. Extensive Google time leaves me thinking there is no substitute. Is this the case? If there are alternatives can you recommend one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know jUDDIv3 brings its own UDDI client.

see: http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_SOA_Platform/5.0.0-Beta1/html/jUDDI_User_Guide/chap-Using_jUDDI-Client.html

I didn't find the lib as a separate download but it is included in the juddi-portal-bundle.

Comment: I've actually been looking over that very page, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to programatically access the UDDI database to get and place services.

Comment: In section 5.7 there is the sample code of how to authenticate to a uddi v3 server.
You can use this sample and extend it by using the transport Object to get to the Inquery and PublishService.

something like this should be possible:
UDDIInquiryPortType query = transport.getInquiryService();
UDDIPublicationPortType publish = transport.getPublishService();

For now I can't give you the complete code sample 'cause I have no functioning server at hand. The only thing I can give you for now is the link to the Javadoc maybe this helps:
http://ws.apache.org/juddi/apidocs3/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jUDDI has its own UDDIv3 client.

Here's the maven details
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.juddi</groupId>
    <artifactId>juddi-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
   </dependency>

There's tons of examples in the current source trunk, all of which will be bundled with future versions. The examples can be found here:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-examples/

The jUDDI user guide is also a great reference too.

Answer (score 0):

i try the following code in 3.0.4 juddi portal bundle

```
/*
 * Copyright 2001-2010 The Apache Software Foundation.
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */


import org.apache.juddi.api_v3.Publisher;
import org.apache.juddi.api_v3.SavePublisher;
import org.apache.juddi.v3.client.ClassUtil;
import org.apache.juddi.v3.client.config.UDDIClientContainer;
import org.apache.juddi.v3.client.transport.Transport;
import org.apache.juddi.v3_service.JUDDIApiPortType;
import org.uddi.api_v3.AuthToken;
import org.uddi.api_v3.BusinessDetail;
import org.uddi.api_v3.BusinessEntity;
import org.uddi.api_v3.BusinessService;
import org.uddi.api_v3.GetAuthToken;
import org.uddi.api_v3.Name;
import org.uddi.api_v3.SaveBusiness;
import org.uddi.api_v3.SaveService;
import org.uddi.api_v3.ServiceDetail;
import org.uddi.v3_service.UDDIPublicationPortType;
import org.uddi.v3_service.UDDISecurityPortType;

public class SimplePublish {
    private static UDDISecurityPortType security = null;

    private static JUDDIApiPortType juddiApi = null;
    private static UDDIPublicationPortType publish = null;

    public SimplePublish() {
        try {
            String clazz = UDDIClientContainer.getUDDIClerkManager(null).
                getClientConfig().getUDDINode("default").getProxyTransport();
            Class<?> transportClass = ClassUtil.forName(clazz, Transport.class);
            if (transportClass!=null) {
                Transport transport = (Transport) transportClass.
                    getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("default");

                security = transport.getUDDISecurityService();
                juddiApi = transport.getJUDDIApiService();
                publish = transport.getUDDIPublishService();
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public void publish() {
        try {
            // Setting up the values to get an authentication token for the 'root' user ('root' user has admin privileges
            // and can save other publishers).
            GetAuthToken getAuthTokenRoot = new GetAuthToken();
            getAuthTokenRoot.setUserID("root");
            getAuthTokenRoot.setCred("");

            // Making API call that retrieves the authentication token for the 'root' user.
            AuthToken rootAuthToken = security.getAuthToken(getAuthTokenRoot);
            System.out.println ("root AUTHTOKEN = " + rootAuthToken.getAuthInfo());

            // Creating a new publisher that we will use to publish our entities to.
            Publisher p = new Publisher();
            p.setAuthorizedName("my-publisher");
            p.setPublisherName("My Publisher");

            // Adding the publisher to the "save" structure, using the 'root' user authentication info and saving away. 
            SavePublisher sp = new SavePublisher();
            sp.getPublisher().add(p);
            sp.setAuthInfo(rootAuthToken.getAuthInfo());
            juddiApi.savePublisher(sp);

            // Our publisher is now saved, so now we want to retrieve its authentication token
            GetAuthToken getAuthTokenMyPub = new GetAuthToken();
            getAuthTokenMyPub.setUserID("my-publisher");
            getAuthTokenMyPub.setCred("");
            AuthToken myPubAuthToken = security.getAuthToken(getAuthTokenMyPub);
            System.out.println ("myPub AUTHTOKEN = " + myPubAuthToken.getAuthInfo());

            // Creating the parent business entity that will contain our service.
            BusinessEntity myBusEntity = new BusinessEntity();
            Name myBusName = new Name();
            myBusName.setValue("My Business");
            myBusEntity.getName().add(myBusName);

            // Adding the business entity to the "save" structure, using our publisher's authentication info and saving away.
            SaveBusiness sb = new SaveBusiness();
            sb.getBusinessEntity().add(myBusEntity);
            sb.setAuthInfo(myPubAuthToken.getAuthInfo());
            BusinessDetail bd = publish.saveBusiness(sb);
            String myBusKey = bd.getBusinessEntity().get(0).getBusinessKey();
            System.out.println("myBusiness key:  " + myBusKey);

            // Creating a service to save.  Only adding the minimum data: the parent business key retrieved from saving the business 
            // above and a single name.
            BusinessService myService = new BusinessService();
            myService.setBusinessKey(myBusKey);
            Name myServName = new Name();
            myServName.setValue("My Service");
            myService.getName().add(myServName);
            // Add binding templates, etc...

            // Adding the service to the "save" structure, using our publisher's authentication info and saving away.
            SaveService ss = new SaveService();
            ss.getBusinessService().add(myService);
            ss.setAuthInfo(myPubAuthToken.getAuthInfo());
            ServiceDetail sd = publish.saveService(ss);
            String myServKey = sd.getBusinessService().get(0).getServiceKey();
            System.out.println("myService key:  " + myServKey);

            // Now you have a publisher saved who in turn published a business and service via the jUDDI API!
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        SimplePublish sp = new SimplePublish();
        sp.publish();   
    }
}
```

and use the following library

maven depandency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.juddi</groupId>
        <artifactId>juddi-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
```

and this jar file

**axis2-adb-1.5.4.jar**

thats it and my code is working fine